# Cambiar el id generado del botón de ninja forms por otro id

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Ninja form genera un id automático en uno de sus elementos, en este caso es un input con el valor "nf-field-4_1".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que necesito hacer es cambiar el id por defecto "nf-field-4_1" por un id personalizado por ejemplo "my-id".

He intentado usar Jquery, de esta manera

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.ninja-forms-field').prop('id', 'my-id');
});
```

También he probado con js puro, usando la consola para ver que lo que estoy haciendo si esta funcionando:

```
console.log(document.getElementById("nf-field-4_1").id);
document.getElementById("nf-field-4_1").setAttribute("id", "my-id");
console.log(document.getElementById("my-id").id);
```

Cuando lo pruebo desde la consola de las herramientas de desarrollador, sí hace efectivo el cambio. Pero cuando lo subo por ejemplo a mi pie de página o algún bloque de código js personalizado, no se actualiza y se queda el id "nf-field-4_1" por defecto.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar este id de una manera más efectiva? Ya que necesito etiquetar ese id de forma diferente para que pueda ser fácilmente reconocido al momento de medir los click en el tag manager y google analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Intenta detectando el Input por su valor

```
jQuery( 'input[value="¡Hablemos!"]' ).attr( 'id', 'my-id' );
```

Tambien puedes probar por el propio ID

```
jQuery( '#nf-field-4_1' ).attr( 'id', 'my-id' );
```

Usando attr le asignas un atributo, si ya posee uno entonces lo reemplaza